# Create a AWS Lambda layer using Docker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am trying to follow the instructions on this page:
[How do I create a Lambda layer using a simulated Lambda environment with Docker?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-simulated-docker/)
on a Windows 7 environment.

I followed all of these steps:

- installed Docker Toolbox
- created a local folder 'C:/Users/Myname/mylayer' containing requirements.txt and python 3.8 folder structure
- run the following commands in docker toolbox:
  `cd c:/users/myname/mylayer`
  `docker run -v "$PWD":/var/task "lambci/lambda:build-python3.8" /bin/sh -c "pip install -r requirements.txt -t python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/; exit"`

It returns the following error:
`ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'`

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Maybe something obvious (I'm a beginner) but I spent the whole day trying to figure it out and it is getting quite frustrating. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

I ran the following in Windows 10 Powershell and it worked

```
docker run -v ${pwd}:/var/task "amazon/aws-sam-cli-build-image-python3.8" /bin/sh -c "pip install -r requirements.txt -t python/lib/python3.8/site-packages; exit"
```